SqlAchemy bulk inserts
I want to enter sessions in bulk or erase them in the same manner.
But sometimes I have 1 record for bulk or 2 records.
Will it affect performance and be expensive in such cases, or sqlalchemy knows how to balance the insertion method even if I choose bulk but with singles?
Reference documentation

" sometimes I have 1 session for bulk or 2" I don't understand what you mean by this?

Your docs link is for SQLAlchemy 1.3, which is quite old. Are you really still using that version?

@GordThompson, yes I have some constraints

@snakecharmerb: sorry I meant one record to insert or two

So if you are actually asking "Will using bulk operations impair performance (compared with the normal "unit of work" approach) if the batch only contains 1 or 2 objects?" then maybe it will, but for only 1 or 2 objects (records) why worry about it?

@GordThompson: because I don't have statistics if most of the time the bulk size will justify the bulk operation. So my question is if there is some built-in way to balance between two approaches based on the number of items in a given bulk
